# Bizarre results with Binary Search speeds

Tags: c#, algorithm, binary-search

I wrote this simple program that is supposed to measure Binary search speed on first, middle and last element. Somehow the worst case is always fastest.

```
static void RunBinarySearchTest()
{
    const int arraySize = 1000000; // Adjust the size as needed
    int[] array = new int[arraySize];
    Random rand = new Random();

    // Populate the array with random values and sort it
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        array[i] = rand.Next(0, 100 * arraySize);
    }
    Array.Sort(array);

    // Define targets: first, middle, and last elements
    int firstElement = array[0];
    int middleElement = array[array.Length / 2];
    int lastElement = array[array.Length - 1];

    // Measure Binary Search performance for each case
    MeasureBinarySearch(array, firstElement, "Best Case");
    MeasureBinarySearch(array, middleElement, "Average Case");
    MeasureBinarySearch(array, lastElement, "Worst Case");
}

static void MeasureBinarySearch(int[] array, int target, string caseDescription)
{
    var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();

    int resultIndex = Array.BinarySearch(array, target);

    stopwatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"{caseDescription}: {stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds} ms. Result Index: {resultIndex}");
}
```

Not sure what is happening but I was writing my own BS algorithm first and saw the same result, ended up using the built in function with the same results.

Best Case: 0.0582 ms. Result Index: 0

Average Case: 0.011 ms. Result Index: 500000

Worst Case: 0.0007 ms. Result Index: 999999

Comment: This code measures the performance of the just-in-time compiler and the effectiveness of the processor's caches and branch prediction logic.  Nothing to do with binary search.  A basic way to eliminate these effects is to repeat the test 10 times or by using BenchmarkDotNet.

Comment: Your notion about which element should take the longest assumes a linear search starting at index 0. With a binary search, the middle element of an odd-length array is the **best** case, because the middle element is the first element that the algorithm will try. With an even-length array, the "middle" element could be either the best case, or the worst case, since there are two "middle" elements.

Comment: In addition to @HansPassant 's comment — to measure the difference between the best and worst cases you should use a lower-level language like C++ (not Visual C++!) so that the measurement is not affected by post-processing software such as JIT compiler.